# Support of Azure AD MFA OATH token feature for Office 365 Enterprise E1 users

Tags: azure-active-directory

A user on a Office Enterprise E1 licence can benefit the MFA feature. But can he also use the hardware OATH token support ? Or is it reserved for users attached to E3 licence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware OATH tokens are available for users with an Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license. See [Hardware OATH tokens in Azure MFA in the cloud are now available](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Hardware-OATH-tokens-in-Azure-MFA-in-the-cloud-are-now-available/ba-p/276466).

It has nothing to do with whether you have E3 or E1 license. Even if you are an E3 user, you still need to purchase the Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license to use the hardware OATH token.